# Half of aspnet data values off by 1 index and being stored incorrectly in database

Tags: c#, gridview, parameters, mismatch

I am having issues related to my c# Gridview. During my update method and after passing new row data parameters into my function, all are mapped to the correct values, yet the last 3 values are saved incorrectly in my Oracle DB.

For example: **Search.Update(cat, dog, fish, mouse, rabbit)**
cat and dog are updated correctly in the database, but fish is saving to mouse's column, and mouse is saving to rabbit's column. What could be causing this?

Comment: The cause is incorrect code. How can we help you if you don't show the code that fails to update your database?

Comment: @Steve You can't. 

I figured it out myself, but should I edit my question and use *real* moq data?

Answer (score 0):

to anyone else that has vague issues regarding parameter mismatches in a relational database:

Verify the order you are passing application-side parameters in, **matches** the order they are used in the Procedure.

In reference to my post, my parameters in the application were passed as **cat, dog, fish, mouse, rabbit**

However, in my Stored Proc were listed as 
**cat** IN VARCHAR2, 
**dog** IN VARCHAR2,
**rabbit** IN VARCHAR2, 
**mouse** IN VARCHAR2, 
**fish** IN VARCHAR2